# how to get all content items of a special content type in orchad core

Tags: orchardcore

I'm working with orchard core and I've written my own Apis.
To get content items of a special content type I've used GetRecentContentItemsByContentTypeAsync() function. this function does not get all content items, but I need to get all to write a service with pagination.
I would appreciate it if there is a solution...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably will want to use inject the `YesSql.ISession` directly to create a more specific query.

Something like

```
var query = _session.Query<ContentItem, ContentItemIndex>(x => x.ContentType == "mycontenttype");

var count = await query.CountAsync(); // for pagination
var results = await query.Skip(0).Take(10).ListAsync();
```

or for a more complex set

```
using YesSql.Services;
var contentTypes = new [ "contenttype1", "contenttype2" ];
var query = _session.Query<ContentItem, ContentItemIndex>(x => x.ContentType.IsIn(contentTypes));
```